# Get all elements by mask

Tags: javascript

Get all elements like this without jQuery

```
<input type="checkbox" name="IB_PROPERTY_415_DEL" id="IB_PROPERTY_415_DEL" value="Y">
<input type="checkbox" name="IB_PROPERTY_417_DEL" id="IB_PROPERTY_417_DEL" value="Y">
```

Where 415 changing every iteration, with whole values (414, 416, etc)
Other checkbox with other names exist on page
I needs one time solution, for console script

Comment: do they have some root element?

Comment: no, they in table cell without class or id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a loop?

```
var elements = [];
for (var i=415; i<418; i++)
    elements.push(document.getElementById("IB_PROPERTY_"+i+"_DEL"));
```

(The unique identifier should be enough)

If you don't know the ids, you could try this:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox][value=Y]");
var elements = [];
for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
    if (inputs[i].name == inputs[i].id && /^IB_PROPERTY_\d{3}_DEL$/.test(inputs[i].id))
        elements.push(inputs[i]);
```

(Note that [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) won't work in all browsers, see @Matt's solution for a better way)

Comment: Aren't them? You can't use a regexp as a css selector.

Answer (score 3):

Without using jQuery (or at least Sizzle), requires quite a bit of work:

```
function getMatchingEls() { 
    // Get all the input elements
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    // This regex matches the varying `name` attributes you have
    var regex = /^IB_PROPERTY_\d+_DEL$/
    // This is what we store matches in
    var matches = [];

    for (var i=0;i<els.length;i++) {
        var curr = els[i];

        // Check it's a checkbox, and it's name matches the expression
        if (curr.type === "checkbox" && regex.test(curr.name)) {
            matches.push(curr);
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the elements on the page, write a regular expression to test each id with such matching string and store them in a separate array. This array would contain the elements you want.

Comment: I am understand that, but i needs quick solution, but without jQuery it's hard for me

Answer (score 0):

If all element has root element, get all childs from it, then filter out ones you need:

```
var mathched = [];
var elements = document.getElementById('root').childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].id.match("IB_PROPERTY_\\d+_DEL")) {
    matched.push(elements[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```js
function get_checkboxes() {
    var cboxes = new Array();
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var len = inputs.length;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        //if (inputs[i].name && inputs[i].name.indexOf('IB_PROPERTY_')==0) {
        if (inputs[i].name && inputs[i].name.match("IB_PROPERTY_\\d+_DEL")) { // this test is better test as alexanderb suggests
            cboxes.push(inputs[i]);
        }
    }
    //alert(cboxes.length);
    return cboxes;
}
```